# Adding text in the middle of the file

Tags: python, file

I have these files:

actions.js - append before }

```
import {constants} from "./constants";

export const setUser = (value) => ({
    type: constants.SET_USER,
    payload: value,
});
//here
```

constants.js - append to the end

```
export const constants = {
    SET_USER: "SET_USER",
    //here
};
```

reducers.js - add a const above `export` and inside the `combineReducers` object

```
import {constants} from "./constants";
import {combineReducers} from "redux";
const user = (state = null, action) => action.type === constants.SET_USER ? action.payload : state;
//here
export const reducers = combineReducers({
    user,
    // here
})
```

And I want to add code into these files in the places where I put //here. How can I do that with Python? I know I can write over a file with `open('file', 'w').write('string')` but how can I actually add text without loosing and overwriting the file? I want to ***add*** the text to the existing file, not to create the file, or overwrite it. I want it to have the old text, and add the new text to it. How can I achieve this with Python?

I made it append to the actions.js like this:

```
import sys
import os

reducer = sys.argv[1]

open("actions.js","a").write("""export const set{reducer} = (value) => ({{
    type: constants.{constant},
    payload: value,
}});
""".format(reducer=reducer.capitalize(), constant=constant))
```

But I have no idea how to get the others done

Comment: Have you googled `add the text to the existing file, not to create the file`?

Comment: I kind of see how to append the text, but I cannot see how to add the text to the middle of the file

Comment: Read the file, slice the string at index you want, concatenate in order, and then write to the file with cursor at 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is not possible in the way you suggest in a single operation. My solution of choice would be to iterate over the file’s lines, and once you hit your `// here` - marker, insert the code.

```
new_content = ""
with open(file_name) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        new_content += line
        if line.strip() == "// here":
            new_content += text_to_insert
```

After this loop, `new_content` should hold the old text and the new* inserted at the right place, which you can then write to any file you like.

*assuming that your input is properly formatted, including line breaks and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Read the file, slice the string at index you want, concatenate in order, and then write to the file with cursor at 0. Let x.txt be your file. "export" in the index() method here refers to a unique non repeating word. You can use unique comments to slice the string at respective positions!

```
with open("x.txt","r+") as f:
  old=f.read()
  print(old)

  constant_text= "What you want to add??"

  result=old[0:old.index("export")] + constant_text + old[old.index("export"):]
  # print(result)
  f.seek(0)
  f.write(result)
  print("######################################")
  print(result)
```

Make sure the index keywords are unique if you want to slice in multiple locations using keywords!

[image: Here's the output]